# change time format to another time format in a string

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to write a function to change the time format and an offset is used to shift the date

For example, I have a string

"this is a string 2012-04-12 23:55 with a 2013-09-12 timezone"

I want to change it to something like:

"**this is a string 20-Apr-2012 13:40 with a 19-Sep-2013 timezone**"

That is, the format of the data change from yyyy-mm-dd to dd-bbb-yyyy and the date is shifted by offset.

I write the following function but it only gives

"this is a string 20-Jun-2012 13:40 with a 2013-11-12 timezone"
but I want something like

"**this is a string 20-Apr-2012 13:40 with a 19-Sep-2013 timezone**"
Here is my code

```
import re
import time
import datetime

def _deIDReportDate(report, offset=654321):
redate = re.compile(r"""([0-9]+-[0-9]+-[0-9]+\s+[0-9]+:[0-9]+)|([0-9]+-[0-9]+-[0-9]+)""")
match = redate.search(report)
for match in redate.finditer(report):
    dt = match.group()
    if len(dt) > 10:
        dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(dt, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
        dt += datetime.timedelta(seconds=offset)
        new_time = dt.strftime('%d-%b-%Y %H:%M')
        newReport = report[:match.start()] + new_time + report[match.end():]
        return newReport
    else:
        dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(dt, '%Y-%m-%d')
        dt += datetime.timedelta(seconds=offset)
        new_time = dt.strftime('%d-%b-%Y')
        newReport = report[:match.start()] + new_time + report[match.end():]
        return newReport
```

Can anyone help to fix/improve my code?

Comment: This is an EXACT duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/4274312 - posted by the same user 2 days later and should be deleted.